# How to get non-numeric character from string in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have some strings like "400$", "400£", "$400" or some other currency which I don't know because the user should input this. How to get that currency string and save it into the variable? I don't want to delete it from the string, I want to get and save it in the variable.

I am using Laravel 7.

Comment: Ideally you would have the `currency symbol` and `value` separate meaning you avoid such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getPriceSTR($str)
{
  $str = trim($str);
  if(!empty($str))
  {
     $currency = preg_replace('/[0-9\s]/', '', $str);
     $price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
  }
  return array('price'=> $price, 'currency'=>$currency );
}

$priceRS = getPriceSTR("450 $");
echo $priceRS['price'].' '.$priceRS['currency'];
```

You can add as helper to this getPriceSTR to your project. Everywhere you can use. Than function return a multidimensonal array. price and currency.

Answer (score -1):

You can use preg_replace function which delete all digits from string

```
$currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", "400$" );
```